# Atoi C Помогите с задачей

Tags: c

Задача: Reproduce the behavior of the function atoi (man atop).
Вообще не имею понятия об атои. Может хоть пару слов о решении

Comment: вы не можете загуглить что делает эта функция что ли?

Comment: www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi

Answer (score 1):

Данная функция переводит число введённое строкой в int, необходимо просто пробежаться по массиву символов, проверить является ли символ цифрой и если является, то добавляете его в переменную int, если цифр больше чем одна, то в каждой следующей итерации умножаете переменную на 10, перед добавлением. Чтобы перевести символ в число, надо найти в таблице ASCII, на каких позициях находится символ 0 и 9.

примерная реализация:

```
string s; //вводится с клавиатуры
int num = 0;
if(s[0]>=48 && s[0]<=57)
  num=s[0]-48;
for(int i = 1; i<s.length; ++i){
  if(s[i]>=48 && s[i]<=57){
    num*=10;
    num+=s[i]-48;
  }   
}
```

Comment: Вместо `48` и `57` гораздо лучше использовать `'0'` и `'9'`. То, что числовые коды цифр расположены подряд, гарантируется стандартами C/C++. А вот значения этих кодов - не гарантируются.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* 
 * atoi.c --
 *
 *        Source code for the "atoi" library procedure.
 *
 * Copyright 1988 Regents of the University of California
 * Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this
 * software and its documentation for any purpose and without
 * fee is hereby granted, provided that the above copyright
 * notice appear in all copies.  The University of California
 * makes no representations about the suitability of this
 * software for any purpose.  It is provided "as is" without
 * express or implied warranty.
 */

#ifndef lint
static char rcsid[] = "$Header: /sprite/src/lib/c/stdlib/RCS/atoi.c,v 1.2 89/03/22 00:46:58 rab Exp $ SPRITE (Berkeley)";
#endif /* not lint */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * atoi --
 *
 *        Convert an ASCII string into an integer.
 *
 * Results:
 *        The return value is the integer equivalent of string.  If there
 *        are no decimal digits in string, then 0 is returned.
 *
 * Side effects:
 *        None.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

int
atoi(string)
    register char *string;        /* String of ASCII digits, possibly
                                 * preceded by white space.  For bases
                                 * greater than 10, either lower- or
                                 * upper-case digits may be used.
                                 */
{
    register int result = 0;
    register unsigned int digit;
    int sign;

    /*
     * Skip any leading blanks.
     */

    while (isspace(*string)) {
        string += 1;
    }

    /*
     * Check for a sign.
     */

    if (*string == '-') {
        sign = 1;
        string += 1;
    } else {
        sign = 0;
        if (*string == '+') {
            string += 1;
        }
    }

    for ( ; ; string += 1) {
        digit = *string - '0';
        if (digit > 9) {
            break;
        }
        result = (10*result) + digit;
    }

    if (sign) {
        return -result;
    }
    return result;
}
```